# Elevation profile and chemical concentrations

Tags: arcgis-desktop, elevation, arcgis-10.4, inverse-distance-weighted

I have a IDW layer showing the pattern of a chemical concentration. I have also created an elevation profile across the same area.

Is there any way to include the IDW measurements with my elevation profile?

Using Arc 10.4.1, I can create an elevation profile like this one below, can I 'fill in' the area below the line with the IDW layer?

[image]

Comment: If you open the graph properties, you can add another series.  Make the elevation profile a line, and the IDW data area under line.

Comment: @jbalk with another sentence or two I think your comment would be enough to qualify as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [commented by @jbalk](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/226418/elevation-profile-and-chemical-concentrations#comment350077_226418) something to try may be:

> If you open the graph properties, you can add another series. Make the
>   elevation profile a line, and the IDW data area under line.